# My Class is returning null even after instantiating it c#

Tags: c#, list, class, unity-game-engine

the class that I've made:

```
 public class singleWeeklyWorking_Period 
    {   // this class holds a single period of work schedule, that can appear weekly on specific days
        public bool[] onDays = new bool[7]; // 7 days a week, set to true on days that this period appears
        public int startTime = 0; // in minutes
        public int endTime = 0;

        
        public void show() // just for testing
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("days: " + onDays[0] + ", "+ onDays[1] + ", "+ onDays[2] + ", "+ onDays[3] + ", "+ onDays[4] + ", "+ onDays[5] + ", "+ onDays[6]);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("startTime: " + startTime);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("endTime: " + endTime);
        }
    }
```

the code that uses the class (just for testing):

```
    public List<singleWeeklyWorking_Period> listOfWeeklyWorkingTime ; 
    // lists of working time


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        singleWeeklyWorking_Period period = new singleWeeklyWorking_Period();
        period.onDays[0] = true;
        period.startTime = 60;
        period.endTime = 120;
        listOfWeeklyWorkingTime.Add(period);

        listOfWeeklyWorkingTime[0].show();
    }
```

as you can see in "singleWeeklyWorking_Period period = new singleWeeklyWorking_Period();". I instantiated the class. but it still gives me an error that says:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

is it the variable inside the class? but I've set it just before I add it to the list:

```
period.onDays[0] = true;
period.startTime = 60;
period.endTime = 120;
```

I'm quite confused, all the help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you creating `listOfWeeklyWorkingTime ` ?

Comment: From the code you've shown it looks like the list will be null

Comment: As said above, you didn't instantiate the list (`listOfWeeklyWorkingTime`), therefore when you try to `.Add` something in that (`null`) list, it throws that exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have not initiated list.

You have this line.

```
public List<singleWeeklyWorking_Period> listOfWeeklyWorkingTime ;
```

Use this instead.

```
public List<singleWeeklyWorking_Period> listOfWeeklyWorkingTime = new List<singleWeeklyWorking_Period>() ;
```

Note: I am assuming that error is when you try to add object.

Comment: Even better for a Unity context would be to simply make the class `[Serializable] public class singleWeeklyWorking_Period { ... }` this way it a) can be exposed and configured in the Inspector in Unity b) can be saved and c) the Inspector would already auto-initialize this array as part of the deserialization .... so once everything is configured in the Inspector `Start` could actually be reduced to the line `listOfWeeklyWorkingTime[0].show();`

Answer (score 0):

A class or struct definition is like a blueprint that specifies what the type can do. An object is basically a block of memory that has been allocated and configured according to the blueprint. Instances of classes are created by using the `new` operator so you need to use it.

```
 public List<singleWeeklyWorking_Period> listOfWeeklyWorkingTime = new List<singleWeeklyWorking_Period>();
```

Comment: So basically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69674042/7111561)